# Spark CSV Escape Not Working

Tags: apache-spark, spark-csv

I am using spark-core version 2.0.1 with Scala 2.11. I have simple code to read a csv file which has \ escapes.

```
val myDA = spark.read
      .option("quote",null)
    .schema(mySchema)
    .csv(filePath)
```

As per documentation \ is default escape for csv reader. But it does not work. Spark is reading \ as part of my data. For Ex: City column in csv file is **north rocks\,au** . I am expecting city column should read in code as **northrocks,au**. But instead spark reads it as **northrocks\** and moves **au** to next column.

I have tried following but did not work:

- Explicitly defined escape .option("escape","\")
- Changed escape to | or : in file and in code
- I have tried using spark-csv library

Any one facing same issue? Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: can replace the way you separate between these? lie `north rocks:au`. I would also try wrapping the whole thing in quotes like `'north rocks\,au'`

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have control over input file.

Comment: This could be the cause: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CSV-135

Comment: Interesting finding: Escaping works if data is quoted but not otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

So escape will only work with quotes. Recommendation is to use quotes if you want to escape.

https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/390